# Having difficulties centering input and text with borders

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, margin

I am having difficulties centering a an input and borders around text that I created. I am trying to center it with a percentages based setting, so that it becomes more responsive. It seems the percentages are off and every time I go over `left: 35%;`, it does not move over anymore.

The same applies to my submit button, inside of the search input. I took the percentage left out because it did not do anything.

I have stored all of my code inside of this fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/ghp4t489/

But, to get the best option to view what I am trying to do, is to visit my website. realtorcatch.com/test_index

How can I get the text with borders/search bar to be centered in the page?

Here is my CSS

```
.search_option_container_out {
    text-align: center;
    top: 450px;
    left: 30%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 111;
}
.search_option_box {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    left: 40%;
}
.search_option_box li {
    display: inline;
    border: 1px solid black;
    line-height: 2em;
    padding: 20px 75px;
    background: rgba(24, 24, 24, 0.3);
    color: #FFFFFF;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.search_option_box li:hover {
    background: rgba(0,0,255, 0.3);
}
.home_searchbar_out {
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 60px;
}
.home_searchbar {
    padding: 10px;
}
.home_search_input {
    position: absolute;
    left: 45%;
    width: 575px;
    padding: 14px;
    font-size: 1.1em;
}
#home_search_submit {
    padding: 11px 20px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: blue;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your code demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/ghp4t489/4/

essentially, you want to use the concept of centering a container inside the page like so:

```css
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div>my div here</div>
```

this code is using `margin: auto` to center the div in the page.

**EDIT:** https://jsfiddle.net/ghp4t489/7/ with button on the right and next to the input

https://jsfiddle.net/ghp4t489/9/ with button on right inside the input

Comment: This is for the OP, in order for `margin: auto;` to work a _width_ must be defined.

Comment: Awesome! That definitely helped. What about the submit button though? I cannot figure out how to get that inside of the search input, on the right side and for it to be somewhat responsive.

Comment: @Becky, so for your button, can i ask why you would like it inside the search input - or do you just want them to be "connected"? and your demo had it on the left side, would you like it on the right side or left side?

Comment: @indubitablee I just think it looks really clean that way. I want it on the right. I couldn't get that button on the right side for some reason in my demo or on my site. You can see now, how it is on the right of my site. I know I could probably do a negative margin-left, but I don't like using negative figures, and I want it to responsive, so that would be counter-productive. I want it to be inside of the input.

Comment: @indubitablee Thanks! Is negative margin the only solution though? How will that translate in terms of responsiveness?

Comment: @Becky, I'm unsure if negative margin is the only solution, i know its the simplest solution though. In terms of responsiveness, it wont affect the responsiveness of the inputbox or the container div you are centering in the page because margins work relative to the element's starting point - so in essence its saying: "where should this be? now move it this many pixels to the left"

Comment: @indubitablee Great explanation and answer! Thank you very much!